# Dynamically create css classe in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create a CSS class with media queries based on input image. The react script to create the css should look something like this:

```
  const getBackgroungImageSet = (image) => {
    return `.mycontainer {    
                background-image:url("${image}?mw=500"); // big image   
            }
            
            @media(max-width: 768px){
              .mycontainer {
                    background-image:url("${image}?mw=250"); // small image  
                }
            }`;
  }
```

Is it possible to add this class to the document in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to add your styles via a style tag. The actual method is based on something shown in the docs for [React Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet). Which is a good way of getting your style tags to the document head instead of arbitrarily in the middle of the dom.

For the style tag, you need to use `type="text/css"` and use a string so that there aren't syntax errors due to CSS syntax not being valid in JSX.

```js
function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>This should be purple</span>
      <br/>
      <span>This should have a blue border</span>
      <style type="text/css">{`
        span {
          color: purple;
        }
        span:nth-of-type(2){
          color: inherit;
          border: 2px solid blue;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```